# systemctl suspend=resume failed (ssd NVME)

Tags: linux, arch-linux, suspend, manjaro

I am a confirmed user of linux for many years but I have an insoluble problem.

- I bought a little ago, a desktop under ryzen 2200g asus 320M-K motherboard. The computer has a basic ssd M.2 sata.
  I changed this one share an intel nvme M.2 760P ssd. And since then I have the problem of not going out of standby state (suspend to ram)
- When I run systemctl suspends the pc is well watch but when the pc goes out of standby the pc is frozen. I think ssd is not back on the road.
  So as ssd does not get back on track, journalctl -b -1 does not teach me anything during the last boot.
- I tried different kernel (4.19, 5.1, 5.2) and I have the problem on all.
  I also tried different option passed to the kernel from grub without result (acpiphp.disable = 1, pcie_aspm = off, ..).
  I use manjaro on this pc, but I also tried opensuse and kubuntu which gives the same result: a freeze during the resume.
- I would be very happy if someone helped me to clear the problem.
  It's good by changing the ssd by the nvme that I had the problem. Nothing else. That's why I suspect this change is causing my problem.

Thank you

ps: [sudo nvme get-feature -f 0x0c -H /dev/nvme0](https://vim.cx/?d50f3778e0767d16#7foN39SGR7ibG8wDQeJsPbn34JPwVnn3zERrZn9TiegQ)

Comment: FYI, I have a motherboard ASUS 320M-K with a bios of June 2019.An update dating from 01/08/2019 solved the problem